# How to verify if creativeId is null

Tags: javascript, adsense, double-click

I was using this piece of code to verify if the `creativeId` is null, but it suddenly stopped working.

```
googletag.pubads().addEventListener('slotRenderEnded', function(event) {
    if(event.slot.k.indexOf('_super_superior')>0) {
        if(event.creativeId!=null) {
            alert('DFP');
        }
        else {
            alert('Adsense');
        }
    }
});
```

It seems that creativeId is now always undefined and then I can't run the function.

Is there any other way to verify if `creativeId` is null so I can detect what ad is DFP and what is AdX?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try like this:

```
if(event.creativeId!=null || event.creativeId!= undefined)
```

Comment: @gillesc:- Yes that was a typo but fixed that very moment I got the downvote :(

Answer (score 2):

Your code, as written, will distinguish between `null` and non-`null` values however `null` is not the same as `undefined`.

To test explicitly for `null`:

```
if (event.creativeId === null) { ... }
```

To test explicitly for `undefined`:

```
if (event.creativeId === undefined) { ... } // preferred by Crockford
```

or

```
if (typeof event.creativeId === 'undefined') { ... }
```

Given your existing logic, you may simply want to use ["falsiness"](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/) to control branching:

```
googletag.pubads().addEventListener('slotRenderEnded', function(event) {
    if (event.slot.k.indexOf('_super_superior') > 0) {
        if (event.creativeId) { // if event.creativeId exists / is numeric and non-zero / is a non-empty string / etc.
            alert('DFP');
        } else {
            alert('Adsense');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, checking against the string `'undefined'` doesn't work as `undefined` is not a string, the string `'undefined'` is when checked against `typeof` result.

```
if (event.creativeId!=null || event.creativeId != undefined)
```

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6nfvqyju/2/)

The `typeof` way would be something like this instead `typeof event.creativeId !== 'undefined'`